# Why Does Iptables rules not persisten by default?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I would be happy if I can learn why iptables rules do not exist persistent if saved by default without any effort to install a new package named netfilter-persistent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with that.

- Not everybody uses `iptables` program directly. Some people may use wrappers, e.g. `ufw`. In that case, it is better to not to store raw rules, but make a wrapper to generate them from its own persistent config.
- Several tools around iptables don't expect its persistence. For example, if you use `fail2ban`, it adds iptables rules when jail starts and removes them when it stops. If you save rules with netfilter-persistent in between, and reboot a host, it'll remember everything that fail2ban did and then, when fail2ban starts, it adds everything again. After several cycles, you'll find your iptables bloated with duplicated fail2ban stuff.

There may be other issues. So you use raw rule persistence when you know you need exactly that. Certainly not everybody needs it.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it very well.